# cakephp + post data is null

Tags: php, cakephp, post

I have created a form using the above code but I submit them I got empty data.

I try to debug that by

```
debug($this->data); //exit;
pr($_FILES); 
pr($this->request->data); die;
```

but data is empty.

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create(false, array(
    'class' => 'form-horizontal',
    'type' => 'file',
    'novalidate' => true,
    'url' => '#users/test/background',
    'id' => 'basic_form_validation',
));
?>

<div class="item in">
    <div class="change-background">
        <label>
            Change Background :
        </label>
        <input type="file" name="background" id="background" value="" />
        <input type="hidden" name="userid" value="<?= $user['id']; ?>" />
    </div>
</div> 
<input type="submit" value="Change" name="change" />
<?php echo $this->Form->end(); ?>
```

Generated form is:

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="basic_form_validation" novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal" action="#users/businesses/background">
<div style="display:none;"><input type="hidden" value="POST" name="_method"></div>
<div class="item in">
    <div class="change-background">
        <label>
            Change Background :
        </label>
        <input type="file" value="" id="background" name="background">
        <input type="hidden" value="20015" name="userid">
    </div>
</div> 
<input type="submit" name="change" value="Change">
```

How can I fix this issue and what is the issue.

Comment: Take a look at the generated source code by pressing `CTRL+U` or `F12`

Comment: @PhiterFernandes : That is the output `<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="basic_form_validation" novalidate="novalidate" class="form-horizontal" action="#users/businesses/background">`

Comment: The full form source code. I don't know much about cakephp but perhaps the form is being generated wrong.

Comment: why you using hash # ?

Comment: `#` is use because of my url structure. and I am getting data but suddenly it stops

Comment: @PhiterFernandes : check the updated code.

Comment: it's can't be with hash, your form action must be pointed to controller method.

Comment: @Salines : but it is redirecting me to the desire function which is `businesses`.

Answer (score 0):

> 'url' => '#users/test/background'

You don't need to write the url, the form helper do it for you and correctly

one example of form with image upload

```
<?= $this->Form->create($category, ['role' => 'form', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) ?>
        <?php
        echo $this->Form->input('title', ['label' => 'title', 'placeholder' => __('title')]);
        echo $this->Form->file('img', ['label' => 'icon']);

        ?>
        <div class="form-group">
            <?= $this->Form->button(__('Add'), ['class' => 'btn btn-default']) ?>
        </div>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

and the controller

```
public function add()
{
    $this -> set('title', 'Add category');
    $category = $this->Categories->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $category = $this->Categories->patchEntity($category, $this->request->data);
        if ($this->Categories->save($category)) {
            $this->Upload->send($category->img, $category->id);
            $this->Flash->success(__('Data saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('Couldn\'t save data'));
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('category'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['category']);
}
```